# Can a model have two associations to the same model, using :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Let's say I have three models: Organization, Skills and Assessments.

Can an Assessment belong to **two different Organizations**, via different relations?

For example, an assessment may have **happened at** organization A, but was **based on** a skill belonging to organization B.

Below are my models and associations:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checklists
  has_many :levels, :through => :checklists
  has_many :sections, :through => :levels
  has_many :skills, :through => :sections
  has_many :assessments_using_own_checklists, :through => :skills, :source => :assessments
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_one :level, through: :section
  has_one :checklist, through: :level
  has_one :organization, through: :checklist
  has_many :assessments
end

class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skill
  has_one :section, through: :skill
  has_one :level, through: :section
  has_one :checklist, through: :level
  has_one :checklist_owner, through: :checklist, source: :organization
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

Using the above, I can get an assessment's organization:

```
Assessment.last.organization # yields organization 1
```

I can also get an assessment's checklist_owner:

```
Assessment.last.checklist_owner # yields organization 2
```

But when I try to use `checklist_owner` in a `where`, the association seems to forget to use the `:through`. For example, if I run:

```
Assessment.where(organization: Organization.find(2), checklist_owner: Organization.find(1))
```

... this translates to SQL:

`SELECT "assessments".* FROM "assessments" WHERE "assessments"."organization_id" = 2 AND "assessments"."organization_id" = 1`

See how the SQL has two `"assessments"."organization_id" =` statements? Why does it do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `joins`?

something like:

`Assessment.joins(skill: { section: { level: :checklist } }).where(organization: Organization.find(2), checklists: { organization_id: Organization.find(1) })`

I know it look bad, but it seems that your relation from assessment to checklist is very complicated. This would take care of any weird relations being made.

Comment: I ended up using .merge, actually, but using a similar technique.